# How to get the feed URL(s) from a website?

Tags: http, request, rss, atom-feed

As per [the official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/RSS/Getting_Started/Syndicating), properly setup websites should indicate the URL of their RSS / Atom feed(s) when asked politely:

> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Accept: application/rss+xml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html
> ```
>
> When an HTTP server (or server-side script) gets this, it should
>   redirect the HTTP client to the feed. It should do this with an HTTP
>   302 Found. Something like:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Location: http://example.com/feed
> ```

I'm trying to get this response, without luck:

```
request(
  { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    followRedirect :false,
    accept: ['application/rss+xml', 'application/xhtml+xml', 'text/html']
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('statusCode: ', response.statusCode);
  }
);
```

Yelds

```
statusCode: 200
```

How do I formulate my request so that the website responds with the feed URL(s)?

Comment: OK, I made a (JS) lib that does just that :) https://framagit.org/yphil/feedrat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not common practice for websites to send back their RSS feed from an HTTP request to the home page asking for an **application/rss+xml** MIME type in the **Accept** header. That documentation on Mozilla you've linked is a suggestion I've never seen before after many years involvement in RSS as a developer.

A more established and widely adopted method for a site to identify its RSS feed is a technique called [RSS Autodiscovery](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery). Open the site's home page and look for this tag in the **HEAD** section:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS"
    href="http://feeds.example.com/rss-feed">
```

The **type** attribute can be any of the MIME types for RSS, Atom or JSONFeed feeds.

Answer (score 0):

The material you quote is prefixed with:

> Although this advanced technique for syndication is not required, support of this is recommended, especially for web sites and applications with high performance needs.

If you get HTML back, then you should construct a DOM with an HTML parser and then search it for the appropriate `<link>` element as described in an earlier section of that page.

Comment: That really wasn't my question ; I'm already parsing the DOM of web pages right and left, I just want to know how to get this `302 redirect` **if and when the website is setup to send it back**, of course :/

Comment: @yPhil — What 302 redirect? The one which **the server doesn't give you because it is optional**? If you want to see the redirect then you have to make the request to a URL which actually responds with a redirect.

Comment: If the server *is* setup to return the 302, will I get it with my request? That was my question (I can try and re-formulate again if you still don't understand) and you didn't answer it.